# How do I make Powershell wait until a command is done before continuing?

Tags: powershell

My script uninstalls a Windows Store app before installing the newer version. I need to make sure the uninstall is finished before installing, so how can I make sure I've waited long enough?

```powershell
Remove-Appxpackage MyAppName  
# ~wait here~  
Add-Appxpackage .\PathToNewVersion
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can do this with the [`Start-Job`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849698.aspx) and [`Wait-Job`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849735.aspx) cmdlets:

```powershell
Start-Job -Name Job1 -ScriptBlock { Remove-Appxpackage MyAppName }
Wait-Job -Name Job1
Add-Appxpackage .\PathToNewVersion
```

`Start-Job` will start a new job process that uninstalls the application.  `Wait-Job` will then cause the script to wait until the task is completed before continuing.