# Deferred PowerShell command Output

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell script. Sometimes a command fails but only outputs a message (no error code) that will be missed due to other commands executing.

I don't have an error code to handle, can't break execution and can't match the text output to determine if its an error as it varies widely.

How can I capture that commands output so I can display it at the end of the script?

Comment: how can one make reasonable suggestions without any sample code to check? [*grin*]

Comment: You might be able to workaround this with the [`Start-Transscript`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.host/start-transcript?view=powershell-7) but that is not the right direction to resolve this. **You should fix the script that outputs a *message* (rather then an *error*) when it fails.**

Comment: Start-Job and Wait-Job?  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/27990646/1054225 and you could set a max timeout period with the -Timeout param if you want to limit to a reasonable timeframe in case one command doesn't return.

Answer (score 0):

This can be found in the error object. Error is an array of errors, and `[0]` is the latest error to occur. Error is an object that can be viewed.

`($Error[0]).InvocationInfo.Line`

The line above will give you the whole line in the script, that generated the error. The `InvocationInfo` property will not exist for errors from the command line.